# UILocalNotification didn't showed up

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift2

This is my ReceiveRemoteNotification code.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
        if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
        }

        let notifiAlert = UIAlertView()

        let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [NSObject: AnyObject]
            let alert1 = aps!["alerts"] as? String
            let link1 = aps!["links"] as? String

            notifiAlert.title = alert1!
            notifiAlert.message = link1
            notifiAlert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
            notifiAlert.show()

            print(userInfo)
            print("success")

    }
```

i tried to receive JSON data from my web, my JSON looks like :

```
{"aps":{"alerts":"3","links":"","sounds":"default"}}
```

I did receive the Json data and turn the data to the view. with this code :

```
let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [NSObject: AnyObject]
                let alert1 = aps!["alerts"] as? String
                let link1 = aps!["links"] as? String

                notifiAlert.title = alert1!
                notifiAlert.message = link1
                notifiAlert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                notifiAlert.show()

                print(userInfo)
                print("success")

        }
```

However i only receive when i was using the application, but if i'm not using, i can't receive the notification. but my phone was vibrate or make sound, but no message.

Am i missing something right here ? thanks !

**Added** Here is my full code http://pastebin.com/mkFiq6Cs

**EDIT**

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
             if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
                 PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
             }
 let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [NSObject: AnyObject]
                    let alert1 = aps!["alerts"] as? String
                    let link1 = aps!["links"] as? String

                    notifiAlert.title = alert1!
                    notifiAlert.message = link1
                    notifiAlert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                    notifiAlert.show()

                    print(userInfo)
                    print("success")
}
```

So i have to add this code :

```
  func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [NSObject: AnyObject]
        let alert2 = aps!["alerts"] as? String
        let link2 = aps!["links"] as? String
        print("didReceiveLocalNotification: \(aps)")
        print("didReceiveLocalNotification: \(alert2)")
        print("didReceiveLocalNotification: \(link2)")
    }
}
```

And this at didFinishLaunchingOption :

```
 if let options = launchOptions {
    if let notification = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] as? UILocalNotification {
        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
            let customField1 = userInfo["CustomField1"] as! String
            // do something neat here
        }
    }
}
```

**SOLVED**

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
    if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
        PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
    }
        let notifiAlert = UIAlertView()
        if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [NSObject: AnyObject],
            let alert1 = aps["alert"] as? String,
            let content1 = aps["content-available"] as? String,
            let link1 = userInfo["links"] as? String {
                    notifiAlert.title = alert1
                    notifiAlert.message = link1
                    notifiAlert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                    notifiAlert.show()
            }

        print(userInfo)
        print("success")

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData)
}
```

This works perfectly. ! Thanks to @tskulbru

Comment: You should probably remove your parse applicationId and clientKey from your pastebin code. Or remove the link and create a new without said information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:)` is only called when the application is active. It cant handle app-inactive/background remote notifications.

> If the app is not running when a remote notification arrives, the method launches the app and provides the appropriate information in the launch options dictionary. The app does not call this method to handle that remote notification. Instead, your implementation of the `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` or `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method needs to get the remote notification payload data and respond appropriately.
>
> Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html?hl=ar#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:

As said above, `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification` needs to have additional implementation if it should be able to handle background notifications.

If you instead want just one method to handle all the goodies for you, and don't have a bunch of different methods to implement basically the same thing, Apple has provided a method called `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` to handle all this for you.

You need to implement the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` method instead of this one to handle background notifications. This handles background tasks, and you can then call the completionHandler with the appropiate enum when you are finished (`.NoData` / `.NewData` / `.Failed`).

If you want to have a local notification presented when you receive a remote notification while the application is active you will need to create that in the aforementioned method. And if you want to display an alertview if the application is active, you also need to handle the two scenarios in that method. My recommendation is to switch to `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` instead and implement everything there.

So in your case, I would do something like this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
  PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
  if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
    PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
  } else { 
    let notifiAlert = UIAlertView()
    if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [NSObject: AnyObject],
      let alert1 = aps["alerts"] as? String,
      let link1 = aps["links"] as? String {

      notifiAlert.title = alert1
      notifiAlert.message = link1
      notifiAlert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
      notifiAlert.show()
    }

    print(userInfo)
    print("success")
  }
  completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData)
}
```

I've not tested the code but it should be something like that without too many changes. I havent used Parse so I don't know exactly what `PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)` does, you need to check the documentation for that.

Looks like your apns payload is wrong too. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH107-SW1

In your case:

```
{"aps":{"alert":"alert content","sound":"default", "content-available": 1}, "links":""}
```

You had plural form instead of single form. Look at the url I gave for the allowed keys. The `links` key doesn't exist in aps dictionary, which mean its a custom key and needs to be placed outside the dictionary.

Note that this is the standard push notification way and might not be correct when using Parse.

Comment: Yes, but you still need to create a `UILocalNotification` if you want to have it show up as a notification on your phone while the application is active. If its inactive the system will handle that for you.

Comment: is that what you mean about `UILocalNotification` @tskulbru ??

Comment: yes it was success when opening the application. the alert showed up. However when i'm at home screen while app still running on background, it's just making a vibrate or sound. when i turn off my screen it's nothing. not even sound. @tskulbru or maybe my JSON wrong ?

Comment: Ah, yes your payload is wrong too. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH107-SW1

Comment: what did i miss from my JSON? badge ? and what payload should i use in this case ? i tried to match my JSON alrdy @tskulbru